# Filter rows of dataframe based on combinations of conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say we have df1 with p values:

```
Symbol     p1     p2     p3     p4     p5
AABT       0.01   0.12   0.23   0.02   0.32
ABC1       0.13   0.01   0.01   0.12   0.02
ACDC       0.15   0.01   0.34   0.24   0.01
BAM1       0.01   0.02   0.04   0.01   0.02
BCR        0.01   0.36   0.02   0.07   0.04
BDSM       0.02   0.43   0.01   0.03   0.41
BGL        0.27   0.77   0.01   0.04   0.02
```

and df2 with Fold Changes:

```
Symbol     FC1    FC2    FC3    FC4    FC5
AABT       1.21  -0.32   0.23  -0.72   0.45
ABC1       0.13   0.93  -1.61   0.12   1.03
ACDC       0.23   1.31   0.42  -0.39   1.50
BAM1      -1.33  -1.27  -0.89   1.22  -1.03
BCR        1.43  -0.25   1.29   0.54   0.97
BDSM       1.20   0.23  -1.98  -1.09  -0.31
BGL        0.33   0.12  -1.33  -1.14  -1.23
```

I would like to do the following in df2:

1. Keep rows that in df1, have values < 0.05 in 3/5 of columns or greater
2. Eliminate rows that show discordant signs of FC. FC should be taken into consideration only when the respective p from df1 is lower than 0.05 (i.e. significant)
3. Sort the resulting data in an intuitive order so as to discriminate rows having positive FC from rows having negative FC, and if possible, discriminate rows whose significances in FC arise sequentially (e.g. FC3 FC4 FC5) from others that don't (e.g. FC1 FC3 FC5)

For example, step 1 would result in:

```
Symbol     FC1    FC2    FC3    FC4    FC5
ABC1       0.13   0.93  -1.61   0.12   1.03
BAM1      -1.33  -1.27  -0.89   1.22  -1.03
BCR        1.43  -0.25   1.29   0.54   0.97
BDSM       1.20   0.23  -1.98  -1.09  -0.31
BGL        0.33   0.12  -1.33  -1.14  -1.23
```

and step 2, in:

```
Symbol     FC1    FC2    FC3    FC4    FC5
BCR        1.43  -0.25   1.29   0.54   0.97
BGL        0.33   0.12  -1.33  -1.14  -1.23
```

How can this be achieved? I imagine using a for loop and the count function would do the job for step 1, but steps 2 and 3 look somewhat complicated to me. Thank you in advance for your elegant solutions.

**data**

df1:

```
df1 <- read.table(h=T,strin=F,text="Symbol     p1     p2     p3     p4     p5
AABT       0.01   0.12   0.23   0.02   0.32
ABC1       0.13   0.01   0.01   0.12   0.02
ACDC       0.15   0.01   0.34   0.24   0.01
BAM1       0.01   0.02   0.04   0.01   0.02
BCR        0.01   0.36   0.02   0.07   0.04
BDSM       0.02   0.43   0.01   0.03   0.41
BGL        0.27   0.77   0.01   0.04   0.02")
```

df2:

```
df2 <- read.table(h=T,strin=F,text="Symbol     FC1    FC2    FC3    FC4    FC5
AABT       1.21  -0.32   0.23  -0.72   0.45
ABC1       0.13   0.93  -1.61   0.12   1.03
ACDC       0.23   1.31   0.42  -0.39   1.50
BAM1      -1.33  -1.27  -0.89   1.22  -1.03
BCR        1.43  -0.25   1.29   0.54   0.97
BDSM       1.20   0.23  -1.98  -1.09  -0.31
BGL        0.33   0.12  -1.33  -1.14  -1.23")
```

Comment: Please elaborate on ```Eliminate rows that show discordant signs of FC```

Comment: Yes. Rows that have both significant positive FC and significant negative FC values should be excluded. "Significant" refers to p < 0.05 in df1. For example, ABC1 has significances in FC2, FC3, and FC5, but because FC3 has an opposite sign to FC2 and FC3, this row should be left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how elegant this is, but you can get the result you requested using `apply` and `sapply` with subsetting, like this:

```r
# Create logical matrix telling us whether p values are significant
sig  <- apply(df1[-1], 2, function(x) x < 0.05)

# Create numeric matrix of the sign of each FC (will be either -1 or 1)
sign <- apply(df2[-1], 2, function(x) sign(x))

# Create a vector telling us whether there were 3 or more p < 0.05 in each row
ss1  <- apply(sig, 1, function(x) length(which(x)) > 2)

# Create a vector telling us whether all FC signs match excluding p = ns 
ss2  <- sapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(i) length(table(sign[i,][sig[i,]])) == 1)

# Subset the data frames accordingly:
df1[ss1, ]
#>   Symbol   p1   p2   p3   p4   p5
#> 2   ABC1 0.13 0.01 0.01 0.12 0.02
#> 4   BAM1 0.01 0.02 0.04 0.01 0.02
#> 5    BCR 0.01 0.36 0.02 0.07 0.04
#> 6   BDSM 0.02 0.43 0.01 0.03 0.41
#> 7    BGL 0.27 0.77 0.01 0.04 0.02

df2[ss1 & ss2, ]
#>   Symbol  FC1   FC2   FC3   FC4   FC5
#> 5    BCR 1.43 -0.25  1.29  0.54  0.97
#> 7    BGL 0.33  0.12 -1.33 -1.14 -1.23
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>